# Netty get response using standard sockets

Tags: java, c, netty, nio

Is it possible to send response from Netty server (ServerBootstrap) to standard Java sockets as clients?

I'm trying to wait for result but without any success.

Server:

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
try {
    ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
    serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
        .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG))
        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ResponseHandler());
            }
        });

    ChannelFuture channelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind(Configuration.serverPort).sync();
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
}
finally {
    bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}
```

Handler:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ctx.write(msg);
    ctx.flush();
}
```

Client:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(this.host, this.port);
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
output.write("Test");

int response;
while ((response = in.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Comment: Are you certain the client data actually reach your server ? You create a PrintStream that isn't autoflushed, nor do you manually flush it, which means data shouldn't leave your client at all.

Comment: Yes for sure, my code is a little more complex, I'm sending not "Test" message but created frame, and I'm receiving it on server, parse it and return back, event if I send from server to client message like "Test" or the same like in request I still don't have a response in client. Maybe it is related to asynchronous response, but I'm using normal sockets, could this be a problem?

Comment: Only your client seems to be using standard sockets(presumably maning java.net.Socket). It certainly doesn't matter what the client does (or which language it's implemented in for that matter), as long as it implements the protocol your server expects (and you, the programmer defines the protocol)

Comment: So how should I send response to client? `ctx.write(msg)` is a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with handler, I was using `ChannelInitializer` when I changed it to my handler everything start working perfectly.

```
ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG))
    .childHandler(new ResponseHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is "do you need to use Netty on both Server and Client machines?"  No you don't.  Netty is just an abstraction (albeit a very clever and complex one) on top of standard networking (similar to the networking framework included with the JDK - I take that's what you mean by standard java sockets).

Are you having a problem getting the channelRead on the server side to see anything?

What Netty API version are you using (3, 4 or 5) - this determines what "read" method you use?

Probably also need to show the code for the ServerBootstrap (including the pipeline initializer) so can see where the problem might be.

Comment: I'm using netty 4.0.23.Final, and there is no problem with receiving data by server but by client, using this construction above I'm not getting any response. On server I can read data, process it, and send back response, event when I try to do context.write("Test") in client I'm not getting any data.